# Debug Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I have a cordova app and I am making ajax calls to the server and I want to see the response. There is `fail` which gets called and it returns me response error and I want to properly evaluate that error response. For that, I created a `div` and populates the error responses into that but all I get on my mobile screen is this: `[Object object]`. I want to expand this `object` to see everything since I don't know what is residing in this object. 
This is my ajax call:

```
function getUserDefaultWalletUpdatedBalance()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: request_url('get-default-wallet-balance'),
        type: "get",
        data:
        {
            'user_id': window.localStorage.getItem('user_id'),
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(xhr)
        {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization-Token', `${window.localStorage.getItem('token')}`);
            $('.loader').css('display', 'block'); //show loader
        },
    })
    .done(function(data)
    {
        $('.loader').css('display', 'none'); //hide loader        
        $('.profileDiv').css('display', 'block'); //show page

        if (data.success.status == 200)
        {
            // console.log(data.success);

            $(".av_blance").text(data.success.defaultWalletBalance);
        }
    })
    .fail(function(error)
    {
        $('.loader').css('display', 'none'); //hide loader
        $('.my').text(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
Json.stringify(error)
```

solves the issue for me.